# How to find multiple files in linux using one find command?

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to download multiple files from a linux server where i need to find the files depending on a name pattern,
my file pattern is like this
FCL_20230116_20230117_051156.zip, VET_20230116_20230117_051156.zip,
I am able to get the filenames "FCL_20230116" from a database. but i want to search for this filenames in the server and download them. I am able to perform list on the folder using ls command

```
 ls {FCL_20230117*,VET_20230117*}
```

my filenames are not same all the time.

i am looking for some query like this

```
find . directory -type f -name {FCL_20230117*,VET_20230117*}
```

is there a command like this ?
Please help.
Thank you very much

Comment: `find . directory -type f \( -name 'FCL_20230117*' - o -name 'VET_20230117*' \}` . There are other ways in w more modern versions of `find` but this will work anywhere. ... With an example like this, some of the documentation in `man find` may make more sense. Else you'll have to learn to search for tutorials on find. (look at https:/grymoire.com/unix/). Good luck.

Comment: Also note that `ls {A*,B*}` is a complicated, bash-only way to write `ls A* B*`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine different tests with `-o` ("or"). If omitted, the default is `-a` ("and"). `-a` has higher precedence than `-o` which can be overridden by parenthesizing parts of the expression with `\( ... \)` or `'(' ... ')'`.

```
find . directory -type f -name 'FCL_20230117*' -o -name 'VET_20230117*'
```

(parsed as: (type == f) AND ((name == FCL...) OR (name == VET...)))